# variant of hat problem

Tags: logic

Each member of a team of 100 wizards is to be fitted with a red or a blue hat;
each wizard will be able to see the colors of the hats of his/her teammates, but not the color of his/her own hat.
No communication will be permitted. At a signal each wizard will simultaneously guess the color of his/her own
hat; all the wizards who guess wrong are subsequently executed.
Knowing that the game will be played, the team has a chance to collaborate on a strategy (that is, a set
of schemes—not necessarily the same for each wizard—telling each player which color to guess, based on what
he/she sees). The object of their planning is to guarantee as many survivors as possible, assuming worst-case hat
distribution.
In other words, we may assume the king (the hat-distributing enemy) knows the wizards’ strategy and will do
his best to foil it. How many wizards can be saved?

**Generalizing the problem. What if the number of colors is k, where k ≥3?**

I've already figured out that if there are 2n or 2n+1 wizards, at least n wizards can be saved. So what I did was separate the wizard into groups of two. And one of the wizards in the group guesses the color he/she sees, and the other wizard guesses the color he/she does not see. This can guarantee at least 1 wizard guesses correctly. But I do not know what if there are 3 colors or more than 3 colors.